# CSS box in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, rendering

I've a rendering problem to show a box with background image and border image in IE8 IE7 IE6

My code works in IE9, Safari, Firefox.

```
.myBox {
background : url(image-left.gif) left no-repeat,url(image-right.gif) right no-repeat, url(images-center.png) repeat-x;
height: 50px;
position:relative;
}
```

I've founded a solution to put left and right image in a table:

CSS:

```
table {
    height: 50px;
    position:relative;
}

.myBox {
    background : url(images-center.png) repeat-x; 
}
```

html:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="image-left.gif" /></td>

    <td>my content text</td>

    <td><img src="image-right.gif" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Anyone have a better and elegant solution????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways to do it

- [Cross-Browser Multi-background
  images, including IE](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Cross_Browser_Multi_background_images__including_I-16839.html), CSS way to do it (*as claimed by adobe, haven't tried it myself..*)
- A [jquery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/multiple-bg) to fix it, *although from the comments i am not so sure it works in all cases*

Of-course your method is valid just as well, although it causes you to change your markup..